# Usage of eventMouseEnter in V4 of fullcalendar

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar

I am using V4 of fullcalnedar and I want to display a popup window when the mouse tip hover an event displayed in the calendar and I am using the following code lines. console.log() line appears correctly. But popup doesn't occur. Any idea about this issue?

```
eventMouseEnter: function (info) {
    console.log("-------hover--------");
    tooltip = '<div class="tooltiptopicevent" style="width:auto;height:auto;background:#feb811;position:absolute;z-index:10001;padding:10px 10px 10px 10px ;  line-height: 200%;">' + 'title: ' + ': ' + info.event.title + '</br>' + 'start: ' + ': ' + info.event.start + '</div>';
    console.log("-------"+tooltip);

    $("body").append(tooltip);
    $(this).mouseover(function (e) {
        $(this).css('z-index', 10000);
        $('.tooltiptopicevent').fadeIn('500');
        $('.tooltiptopicevent').fadeTo('10', 1.9);
    }).mousemove(function (e) {
        $('.tooltiptopicevent').css('top', e.pageY + 10);
        $('.tooltiptopicevent').css('left', e.pageX + 20);
    });
},
eventMouseLeave: function (data, event, view) {
    $(this).css('z-index', 8);

    $('.tooltiptopicevent').remove();
}
```

**UPDATED**

With the above code snippet I can have the pop - up. But its not very clearly observed. The screen gets blinked very speedily so that its really hard to see the screen. Do you have any idea?

**UPDATED**

```
<script>
$scope.displayCalendar = function()
{
 var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [ 'dayGrid' ],
    defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
    defaultDate: '2019-06-12',
    eventRender: function(info) {
      var tooltip = new Tooltip(info.el, {
        title: info.event.extendedProps.description,
        placement: 'top',
        trigger: 'hover',
        container: 'body'
      });
    }
events: [
      {
        title: 'All Day Event',
        description: 'description for All Day Event',
        start: '2019-06-01'
      },
      {
        title: 'Long Event',
        description: 'description for Long Event',
        start: '2019-06-07',
        end: '2019-06-10'
      }
       ]
});
calendar.render();

}
```

Comment: why not use a ready-made tooltip library such as tooltip.js, or similar? There's an example in the fullCalendar documentation [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender). There's even a [demo](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-tooltip-demo).

Comment: P.S. I don't know where you got this function signature `eventMouseEnter: function (data, event, view)` from? Clearly in the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventMouseEnter) the signature is `eventMouseEnter: function( mouseEnterInfo ) `. data, event and view are subproperties of that "info" object. Read the documentation more carefully!

Comment: P.P.S. Is there any reason you aren't using the ready-made Angular component for integrating with fullCalendar. See here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular

Comment: @ADyson. Sorry I mistakenly hadn't edit the code regarding the parameters. Now I updated the code.How can I import Tooltip.js file?

Comment: Did you look at the CodePen linked from the demo page? If you look in the JS script files loaded by that it tells you which files you need to load into your page. https://unpkg.com/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js and https://unpkg.com/tooltip.js/dist/umd/tooltip.min.js

Comment: I imported the two js files and used the exact code snippet. But no pop-up is seen. @ADyson

Comment: Did you grab the relevant CSS from the CodePen as well? Any errors in your browser console? Please show us your new code then we can help. Even better, if you can make a demo reproducing your issue that would make it easier.

Comment: @ADyson Yes I have used the css part used in codepen. But didn't import any new css files. I updated the code above. No errors in the console.log also. The eventReder() function is not being called

Comment: "The eventReder() function is not being called" ...you verified this with the debugger, or with a console.log() command, maybe? It really doesn't execute, or you mean you just can't see any results? It's not the same thing. Also, do your events actually have a "description" property? This is not a standard property. Maybe try with the title instead, since that's what you were doing in your original code.

Comment: I put a console.log() inside eventRender function.It doesn't print in the console.console.log() is the first line of the function. So that means the function isn't invoked right? @ADyson

Comment: Yes. But it's pretty odd. I have no idea why that is. Can you make a CodePen which demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @ADyson as you previously mentioned i couldn’t see the libraries imported in the codepen example. Can you direct me to the correct link?

Comment: You mean a link to the demo? Go to https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-tooltip-demo and click "Edit in CodePen" in the top corner.

Comment: I am in doubt if I have imported the js files correctly. In the demo in the edit mode I couldn't see how they have imported tooltip.js and popper.js file @ADyson

Comment: Click the "cog" icon in the top corner of the JS section. It shows you what scripts are loaded. I don't know exactly how the codepen engine goes about loading them into the display frame, but obviously in a normal webpage you use a `<script>` tag

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194550/discussion-between-tharindu-and-adyson).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending more than one and half days I found that the issue is in the CSS related to tooltip. Therefore by adding the following snippet to CSS file I could get over the issue

```
.tooltip
{
opacity: 1;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
eventMouseEnter: function (info) {
        // Display description when hovering over an event
        descriptionEl.innerHTML = info.event.extendedProps.description;
        descriptionEl.style.display = 'block';
        descriptionEl.style.left = (info.jsEvent.pageX + 10) + 'px';
        descriptionEl.style.top = (info.jsEvent.pageY + 10) + 'px';
    },
    eventMouseLeave: function () {
        // Hide description when mouse leaves an event
        descriptionEl.style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>


<style>
    #description {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #fafde9;
        border: 1px solid #090034;
        padding: 5px;
    }
</style>
```

Add this block to the HTML